# Call methods for multiple objects with the names saved in a String[]

Tags: java, swing, object

I have created multiple JtextFields using Netbeans IDE 7.3, with the Design Inerface, and I have stored all object names created in array of Strings.
I would like to create a loop to read the text contained in all JTextFields, in order to print all fields.

For example:

```
I have automatically created:
class.javax.swing.JTextField a_field;
class.javax.swing.JTextField b_field;

class.javax.swing.JTextField a_value;
class.javax.swing.JTextField b_value;
```

*(actually, I have more than 50 fields, not just "a" and "b")

I have listed all in an array of strings

```
String[] allTextFields={"a","b"};
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<allTextFields.length() ; i++){
   String field = (allTextFields[i]+"_field").getText();
   String value = (allTextFields[i]+"_value").getText();

   System.out.println(field + " has value: " + value);
}
```

Because they are already created, I can't declare them as an array of JTextFields... So, what I need is to convert the strings: (allTextFields[i]+"_field") into calls to the defined objects.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Why do you have a `JTextField` for the field name and a separate one for the field value?  If they are already created, what's stopping you from adding them to an array of `JTextField`s?

Comment: @JimGarrison looks like OP wants to retrieve them dynamically by their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your text fields into JPanel, and then you can get all components into the JPanel

For example:

```
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    add(panel1);

    JTextField field1 = new JTextField("field1");
    field1.setName("field1");
    panel1.add(field1);

    JTextField field2 = new JTextField("field2");
    field2.setName("field2");
    panel1.add(field2);

    Component[] components = panel1.getComponents();
    if (null != components) {
        for (Component component : components) {
            if (component instanceof JTextField) {
                System.out.println(((JTextField)component).getText());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks Manitra! I also included a condition to discard other JTextField elements, and it solves the issue.